# How to navigate from one popup page to another using Jquery in struts2 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I wish to navigate through multiple pages in a pop-up block. That is, my main page would be inactive when i navigate through pop-up flow as below

```
[[Main Page]]
    [popup-page1]--Next--> [popup-page2]--Next--> [popup-submit page3] --Submit--> 
[[Main Page]]
```

Each page has different set of attributes that are populated by user input such as radio buttons and text fields etc
for instance, below are some of the attributes that are filled on each page.

```
[page1]--> your name, DOB, country
[page2]--> your preference, your package, direction 
[page3]--> email address and submit
```

How can i retain these values and submit as a form? Do I need to submit each popup page as a separate form or in one shot by retaining all these value till the end?

Note that my application is in strut2 and usually for page navigation I take the help of model driven arch. (putting the fields in one bean and keep a track of value changes using hidden attributes from one form to another)..How can this be achieved using pop-ups. I have limited knowledge about `sj:dialog`

**EDIT**

Use Jquery to simulate pop-up  navigation by display none and block property. Then, for submit do an AJAX call, this will perform an async call in the background.

Comment: Put them in the session

Comment: `I take the help of model driven arch` there is no help from a model drive arch, only problems :D

Comment: submit throug AJAX and remove the popup through javascript

Comment: Using ajax now thats the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to navigate through multiple pages in a pop-up block.

1. I created multiple divs inside the parent div and on click of each continue button I took help of show and hide using Jquery.
2. At the end of the flow, submit the request to an URL using an AJAX call (GET request)pass values entered by user as params.